# facebook number of page views using facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm using [this](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1570694813193723/insights/page_views/lifetime) url for facebook graph api to get page views, and get the following in return:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1570694813193723/insights/page_views/lifetime?debug=all&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1428476277&until=1428735477",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1570694813193723/insights/page_views/lifetime?debug=all&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1428994677&until=1429253877"
    }
}
```

in some queries date time error that must be unix or date time format. I can share you my access token. I urgently need number of page views and also tell me since and until format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function p_view()
            {
                //data:Array[10],
                FB.api("/144765045682596/insights/page_views?period=day&since=1427846400&until=1429142400", function (response) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        var thread = response.data[i].values;
                        var s=13;
                        //if (thread.values[13] == thread.values[i])
                        //{
                        var tm = thread[s].end_time;
                        var th = thread[s].value;
                        document.getElementById('datev').innerHTML = tm;
                        document.getElementById('viewers').innerHTML = th;
                        //    var values = thread.values;
                        //    //var comment = thread.
                        //}
                    }
                });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's all in the docs. And please, spent some time producing a readable question.

The call should be

```
/{page_id}/insights/page_views?period=day&since=1427846400&until=1429142400&access_token={access_token}
```

Replace `{access_token}` with an actual Access Token with `read_insights` permission, and `{page_id}` with a page id. This returns the daily page views from April 1st to April 15th.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#readfields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Comment: "error": "Invalid response"   problem is still this

Comment: I doubt that you're running the correct request. Have you added your User or Page Access Token with `read_insights` permission?

Comment: function p_post() {  FB.api("/209652442394600?fields=posts{admin_creator}", function (response) {
                    var t = response.posts.data.length;   }); }
now in response i m getting 25 by default but if it increase 25posts or views how to handle it

Comment: What does this code have to do with your question? Nothing.

Comment: /1570694813193723/acess_Token=done/insights/page_views?period=day&since=1427846400&until=1429142400
still same error

Comment: The URL you're using is completely incorrect! Have you even read my answer?

Comment: i added permissions and also used token as well as also used your url but still got error  invalid response

Comment: can you give me exact graph explorar url for thanx

Comment: If you would just read my answer and follow what I wrote it would work. The obect with id `1570694813193723` is not a valid page object, therefore it can't work. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Finsights%2Fpage_views%3Fperiod%3Dday%26since%3D1427846400%26until%3D1429142400&version=v2.3& Replace `cocacola` with your page id.

Comment: And, btw, this is my last comment on this. Get your stuff done.